# Irreducible representations of quantum affine algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modules, quantum-groups

The finite dimensional simple modules of quantum affine algebras are parameterized by Drinfeld polynomials. Some other modules of quantum affine algebras are studied in [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.2769). Some infinite dimensional weight modules of type 1 are constructed in [the paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2015-143-12/S0002-9939-2015-12663-9/S0002-9939-2015-12663-9.pdf). I searched on google and didn't find papers about other type of modules of quantum affine algebras (for example, Harish-Chandra modules, Whittaker modules). Are there some work about Harish-Chandra modules (or Whittaker modules) of quantum affine algebras in the literature? Thank you very much.

Comment: Though Google is widely available, so is Google Scholar: for example, https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22representations+of+quantum+affine+algebra%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22  (but on the other hand the mathematics search engine for MathSciNet returns about 300 items dealing with representions of quantum affine algebras).    The point is that there is lots of activity in the subject, and many directions.   Maybe it's simplest for you to contact a specialist directly to get focused advice?